# Create a JSON object to be sent as parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored proc say `sp_proc_1` which takes in a few parameters say `@val1`, `@val2`, and `@val3`. I would like to make a JSON object using the values `@val1` and `@val2` so that I can pass that JSON object as one of the parameters to a second stored procedure `sp_proc2` which I will be invoking from  `sp_proc1`. Please guide.

The way I think is to insert `@val1` and `@val2` into a `temp_table` and then select them from the `temp_table` into a JSON object. Am I thinking right?

Comment: What is the expected JSON? `SELECT @val1 AS val1, @val2 AS val2, @val3 AS val3 FOR JSON PATH` is also an option.

Comment: The expected json is somethng like myjson = [ {"Age": @val1, "name":@val2}] put into a variable and invoke a stored proc EXEC sp_myproc persondata=@myjson

Comment: Sounds like you should probably use a Table Valued Parameter instead. Unless sproc2 *needs* JSON anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement depends on the format of the expected JSON output, but a possible option is `FOR JSON PATH`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_1
   @val1 int,
   @val2 varchar(100),
   @val3 datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
   SET @json = (SELECT @val1 AS val1, @val2 AS val2 FOR JSON PATH)
   
   EXEC Proc_2 @json
END
```

The generated JSON is:

```
[{"val1":1,"val2":"Test value"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15); you just need to build the appropriate select statement:

```
declare @val1 int = 1234;
declare @val2 varchar(100) = 'foobar';
declare @val3 datetime2(3) = sysdatetime();
declare @json nvarchar(max) = (
    select *
    from (values (@val1, @val2, @val3)) as v(val1, val2, val3)
    for json auto, without_array_wrapper
);
select @json;
```